# apache mod_rewrite query string to canonical URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to take a URL that gives me a query string with inputs in a given order and place the values of the query string in a canonical format. For example ...

```
www.example.com/?name=me&value=you&where=here
```

becomes

```
www.example.com/Connects/me/you/here
```

I have tried a few mod_rewrites but I am having difficulty getting it to work. I am not sure what to do with the fact that the query comes right after the base URL - maybe I don't have to do anything. Anyway, here is one of the things that I tried.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^/ /Connects/%1/%2/%3/%4/%5/%6 [L]
```

Comment: Everyone seems to be working on the assumption that the resource is `?name=me&value=you&where=here` rather than `/Connects/me/you/here` - just for clarification, what *exactly* do you expect to see in the address bar?

Comment: The final URL should be /Connects/me/you/here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match on the querystring itself:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(\w+)&value=(\w+)&where=(\w+)
RewriteRule .* /Connects/%1/%2/%3? [L]
```

... though if your canonical URL remaps to an actual page with those parameters you could well end up in an infinitely recursive loop - be careful out there!

Comment: This makes sense to me, but it gives me an error

Comment: Possibly that recursive loop if you've got `/Connects/*` being rewritten; worked on my dev box with no additional `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: I guess that's what is happening, but I don't understand that. There is an actual page at the /Connects URL but I don't see how that is recursive. The /Connects URL is the final destination.

Comment: Mapping the query URL to any other URL also results in the same error.

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't emptying the original query string. Can you add a trailing question mark and I will accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: Ah yeah - good point, well made :) Alternatively using the `QSD` flag should do the same thing - so instead of `[L]` you'd have `[L,QSD]`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand well, but it would be this way:

```
RewriteRule ^Connects/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /?name=$1&value=$2&where=$3 [L]
```

Comment: This caused an internal error

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice. Your route-rules must be inside a php file, not in htaccess.

#### .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

#### index.php

```
<?php
# /Connects/me/you/here
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$parts = explode('/', $uri);
// Array(0=>'', 1=>'Connects', 2=>'me', 3=>'you', 3=>'here')

if( '/Connects/me/you/here' === $uri ) {
    echo "Connects page!";
}

if( '/home' === $uri ) {
    echo "Home!";
}
```

Frameworks use `Routes` to catch `REQUEST_URI` structure and call Controller or Closure function for this route.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rephrase the question, as you seem to be asking about [SEO-Friendly URLs](http://zenverse.net/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess/), but using the term "canonical" which refers to the [consolidation of URLs for SEO purposes.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

From that first link, by the way, you can find the "capturing" function that you probably want to use.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?product=$1&price=$2
```

This "capturing" feature is what you want to use.

So, for

```
www.example.com/?name=me&value=you&where=here
```

You would want to capture like this:

```
www.example.com/?name=$1&value=$2&where=$3
```

Then, use parentheses to output those captures.

```
RewriteRule ^Connects/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ www.example.com/?name=$1&value=$2&where=$3
```

It's worth noting that I formatted this with the assumption you only wanted these to be alpha characters. You'll want to customize based on what values can be accepted.